# Accessing pointees of a shared_ptr's in a deque owned by an object

Tags: c++11, reference, shared-ptr, deque

Let an object A own a deque of shared_ptr's in C++11.
To access the pointee properties and methods of the front of the queue, I would like to get a reference to A->deque().front(), but this does not seem to work as I would expect.

Here is a code extract to narrow the problem: just display the address of the pointee obtained with the shared_ptr get() method, either when using a copy or a reference.

```
auto const  my_copy = A->deque().front();
cout<<"my_copy pointee: "<<hex<<reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(my_copy.get())<<endl;
auto const & my_ref = A->deque().front();
cout<<"my_ref  pointee: "<<hex<<reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(my_ref .get())<<endl;
```

the output reads:

```
my_copy pointee: 7fa222c1be60
my_ref  pointee: 0           <---- Unexpected: should be the same as above
```

But if I use an intermediate reference to the deque, it works as expected

```
auto const & my_deque = A->deque();
auto const  my_copy = my_deque.front();
cout<<"my_copy pointee: "<<hex<<reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(my_copy.get())<<endl;
auto const & my_ref = my_deque.front();
cout<<"my_ref  pointee: "<<hex<<reinterpret_cast<uintptr_t>(my_ref .get())<<endl;
```

the output reads:

```
my_copy pointee: 7fa222c1be60
my_ref  pointee: 7fa222c1be60
```

I have the impression that I really missed something obvious...

Comment: The cast to `uintptr_t` should be unnecessary as long as you are not dealing with `char*`.

Comment: Are you sure `A::deque` is returning by reference and not accidentally by value? http://ideone.com/gRw2bf does behave as intended. The problem must be somewhere else.

Comment: That's what I found: A->deque() was returning by value as a sorted copy of the member deque. The compiler seems very (too?) sensitive on that matter and did not emit any warning that could have helped. Anyway thanks.

Comment: I posted this as an answer, so you can accept it. (Green tickmark).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The code seems correct and the most likely culprit is `A::deque` which probably returns by value. This would cause undefined behavior. The code works with the extra reference since you are extending the lifetime of the temporary to the lifetime of that reference.